# How do i transfer from main eth network to kovan test network in metamask?

Tags: testnets, metamask, kovan

I transferred Ether to the main network in Metamask. This might seem like a stupid question, but how do I transfer that Ether to the Kovan Test Network?

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

You can't transfer ETH from one network to another. You can get free ETH on most testnets though, [here's](https://github.com/kovan-testnet/faucet/blob/master/README.md) a link to information on *faucets* for the Kovan testnet.

There are currently four ways listed on the above link to get Kovan testnet ETH:

> - Icarus Faucet (SMS Verified, Automated)
> - Github Gist Faucet ( Automated )
> - Request Via Gitter (Manually Verified)
> - Use PoW via SmartPool